# Memory allocated to Python is not released back in Linux even after gc.collect()

Tags: python, memory-management, garbage-collection, numpy, malloc

I have written code within Python that doesn't release memory the way it should. The memory is taken by Python but never gets released even after not being used anymore. Even if you break the running program with ctrl+c. Delete the variable and run gc.collect() it doesn't seem to collect. Or the same as in Ipython and running %reset. The memory won't be freed and running gc.collect() has no effect. I tested this in Windows because I wanted to see if it could possibly be with the garbage collector library. It appears that is the case. Run the code below in Linux and then also in windows. Then compare the memory usage. You will need numpy and scipy installed. Any help or insight on this issue would be much appreciated.

Import the Model, create an instance, and then run createSpecific().

Here is a code that exhibits this behavior in Ubuntu 10.04:

```
from numpy import array, maximum,intersect1d, meshgrid, std, log, log10, zeros, ones, argwhere, abs, arange, size, copy, sqrt, sin, cos, pi, vstack, hstack, zeros, exp, max, mean, savetxt, loadtxt,  minimum,  linspace,  where
from numpy.fft import fft
from scipy.stats import f_oneway, kruskal, sem, scoreatpercentile
#import matplotlib
#matplotlib.use('cairo.pdf')
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, clf, show, cla, xlim, xscale, imshow, ylabel, xlabel, figure, savefig, close,  bar,  title,  xticks, yticks, axes, axis
from matplotlib.axes import Axes
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
#from enthought.mayavi import mlab
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from time import clock
from timeit import Timer
class Model:

#Constructors and default includes
    def __init__(self, prevAud = None,  debug=False):

        if (prevAud == None):
            self.fs=16000. #sample rate
            self.lowFreq=60. 
            self.hiFreq=5000.     
            self.numFilt=300 #number of channel
            self.EarQ = 9.26449   #9.26449
            self.minBW = 24.7     #24.7
            self.integrationWindow=.01
            self.sliceAt=.035
            self.maxOverallInhibit = 0.1
            self.winLen = int(self.fs*self.integrationWindow+.01) #default integration window 10 ms
            self.fullWind = 0.300
            self.outShortWindow = None
            self.siderArray = None
            self.maxNormalizeValue = .284     # Optimized at .284
            self.outputSemiModel = None
            self.semitones = 11
            self.activationTrace = None
        return




    def setErbScale(self, erbScale = None):
        if (erbScale ==None):
            self.erbScale = arange(100,500,5)
        else:
            self.erbScale = erbScale        

    def trainModel(self,soundVec=None, fs=None, lowfreq=None, highfreq=None, numfilt=None, figto=0, savefig = 'N', prompts=False, plotter=False):
        self.setErbScale()
        templateArray = self.intWindow(self.halfWaveRec(self.creGammatone(soundVec))) 
        for i in xrange(templateArray[0].size):        
            self.outerTest(self.innerTest(templateArray[:,i]))

        return templateArray   


    def createSpecific(self, freqArray = None, semitones = 11, timeforHarm = .3, soundVec=None, fs=None, lowfreq=None, highfreq=None, numfilt=None, figto=0, saveData='N', fileDir='TempRunT/', prompts=False, plotter=False):
        if (freqArray == None):
            self.setErbScale()
            freqArray = self.erbScale
        if (type(semitones) == int):
            semitones = arange(semitones+1)
        totalRuns = int(timeforHarm/self.integrationWindow+.001)
        inhibitWindowArray = zeros((freqArray.size,(semitones.size),self.numFilt,totalRuns))
        for x in xrange(freqArray.size):
            tempHarm = self.makeHarmonicAmpMod(freqArray[x],timeforHarm, numHarm=7,modulation=10)
            for y in semitones:
                tempChord = self.makeSemiChordAmpMod(tempHarm, freqArray[x],timeforHarm,modulation=10,numHarm=7,semi=y)
                inhibitWindowArray[x,y] = self.trainModel( tempChord, savefig = 'N', plotter=plotter)


        self.inhibitWindowArray = inhibitWindowArray

    def creGammatone(self, soundVec):

        temp = zeros((300,soundVec.size))
        for i in xrange(temp[:,0].size):
            temp[i] = -1**i*soundVec
        return temp

    def halfWaveRec(self, halfWaveFilts):

        filtShape = halfWaveFilts.shape
        if (filtShape[1] != int(self.fs*self.fullWind)):
            halfWaveFilts = hstack((halfWaveFilts,zeros((self.numFilt,int(self.fs*self.fullWind)-filtShape[1]))))
        temp = zeros((halfWaveFilts[:,0].size,halfWaveFilts[0].size))
        halfWaveFilts = maximum(halfWaveFilts,temp)

        del temp                
        return halfWaveFilts

    def intWindow(self, integratedFilts):
        winlen = self.winLen

        length = integratedFilts[0].size/winlen
        mod = integratedFilts[0].size%winlen
        outShortWindow = zeros((integratedFilts[:,0].size,length))
        meanval = 0

        if (mod != 0):
            for i in xrange(integratedFilts[:,0].size):
                mean(integratedFilts[i,0:-mod].reshape(length,winlen),1,out=outShortWindow[i])
        else:
            for i in xrange(integratedFilts[:,0].size):
                mean(integratedFilts[i].reshape(length,winlen),1,out=outShortWindow[i])
        del integratedFilts
        return outShortWindow    

    def innerTest(self, window):
        temper = copy(window)
        sider = 7
        st = .04
        sizer = temper.size
        inhibVal = 0
        for j in xrange(sider):
            inhibVal = (temper[0:j+sider+1].sum())*(sider*2+1)/(sider+1+j)
            window[j] += - st*(inhibVal)
        for j in xrange(sider,sizer - sider):
            inhibVal = temper[j-sider:j+sider+1].sum()
            window[j] += - st*(inhibVal)
        for j in xrange(sizer-sider, sizer):
            inhibVal = (temper[j-sider:sizer].sum())*(sider*2+1)/(sider+sizer-j)
            window[j] += - st*(inhibVal)

        maxsub = max(window) * self.maxOverallInhibit
        window += - maxsub    
        del temper
        return window

    def outerTest(self, window):
        newSatValue = scoreatpercentile(window, (76))
        numones = where(window > newSatValue)
        window[numones]=1
        self.maxSatValue = newSatValue
        del numones
        return window

    def makeHarmonicAmpMod(self, freq = 100, time = 1.,modulation=10, fsamp=None, numHarm=7):
        if fsamp == None: fsamp = self.fs
        samples = arange(time*fsamp)
        signal = 0
        for x in xrange(1,(numHarm+1),1):
            signal = signal + sin(samples/float(fsamp)*x*freq*2*pi)
        signal = (signal)*maximum(zeros(time*fsamp),sin((samples/float(fsamp)*modulation*2*pi)))
        return signal

    def makeSemiChordAmpMod(self, harmVec = None, freq=100, time = 1.,  modulation=10, fsamp=None, numHarm=7, semi = 2):
        if (harmVec == None): harmVec = self.makeHarmonicAmpMod(freq,time,modulation,fsamp,numHarm)
        if (semi == 0): return harmVec
        return harmVec + self.makeHarmonicAmpMod(freq*(2**(semi/12.)),time,modulation,fsamp,numHarm)
```

Comment: The memory allocated by python use malloc() under the hood, and the memory allocated by malloc() is not return to the system after you call free() which what gc.collect() do as far as i know, even that python use it own malloc (PyObject_malloc() and PyObject_Free()) but they have the same behavior look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215259/will-malloc-implementations-return-free-ed-memory-back-to-the-system

Comment: @singularity - I'd be willing to give tcmalloc a try with the instructions to force it to free objects just to see if it works. Do you know how to force it to use that library. Does Python have to be compiled in a special way and linked to that library I assume?

Comment: @J Spen: look here : http://pushingtheweb.com/2010/06/python-and-tcmalloc/ maybe this can give you more detail.

Comment: @singularity - I know about that link but I am unsure of how to compile Python with TCMalloc for the collector but I have posted there to see if they will respond.

Comment: Side note, there really is NO need to manually delete local variables inside functions, classes and code. The python GC is smart enough to realize when you do not need this variable and will sort it out on its own.

Comment: IPython can keep references even after `%reset`, unless you're running the development version, where it should be fixed. See here: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/141

Comment: @Jakob - I know del isn't necessary typically but I added those in during debugging because I was seeing if for some reason it was keeping the references intact and that would release the memory. It has no effect.

Comment: @Thomas K - Interesting note but that is when using %run from reading the notes. I don't run the dev version until Matplotlib fully supports the new features for Ipython 0.11 which as far as I know still isn't fully compatible. Also, the same exact issue above occurs within a regular python shell.

Comment: @J Spen: Just thought I'd mention it in case it makes testing it more confusing. There can also be references left without %run, but the references created by %run are the hardest to track down.

Comment: @J Spen - For whatever it's worth, this doesn't appear to leak memory at all on my machine (Python 2.7, numpy 1.6, OpenSuse 11.4, kernel 2.6.37.6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had installed the latest svn of numpy and the issue had vanished. I assume it was inside one of the numpy functions. I never got a chance to dig further into it.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual memory is not a scarce resource. There is no need to return it to the system since each process has its own address space. What is your actual problem? What issue is this behavior causing you?

Comment: Mobile devices and dev-boards usually don't have virtual memory. They have RAM and that's usually it.

Comment: @jww That is completely untrue and wasn't even true a decade ago. You might find processors without virtual memory as power controllers in things like solar power system and maybe some very small dev boards (like arduino). But that's about it. I haven't seen a mobile device without virtual memory in a decade.

Comment: My bad David. They have virtual memory and each process usually has its own space, but they don't have swap files. You can't treat those devices like desktops or servers. If you do, then you will experience a lot of out of memory kills. I seem to recall the max size for a `malloc` was 32 MB or 64 MB on some of the early iPads, which only had 256 MB of memory.