# Is there a difference in memory treatment of fork for Mac and Linux?

Tags: linux, macos, subprocess, fork

I have been using Python's subprocess module to run some processes using `subprocess.Popen`. I developed the code on my Mac OS, but now I am running it on Linux server. After memory profiling using `resource.getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss` of my Parent and child process, I am finding the memory allocation mechanism as entirely different on two platforms.

I have researched everywhere on the differences in the behaviour of fork under Mac and Linux, but nowhere anything like this is mentioned.

I am running a loop like this:

```
for t in range(1000):
   pid = subprocess.Popen([EXECUTABLES, FILNAME])
   # execute some commands here
   pid.terminate()
   pid.wait()
```

On Mac:

1. The child process has constant RSS
2. The parent process has increasing RSS

On Linux:

1. RSS of child process = RSS of the parent process
2. RSS of the parent process is increasing drastically
3. Which is making child process to increase drastically

Comment: [Memory allocated to Python is not released back in Linux even after gc.collect()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5975255/608639), [Will malloc implementations return free-ed memory back to the system?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2215259/608639), [Memory not freed after calling free()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5365996/608639), etc.

Comment: Somehow those links are not related to the memory allocation during fork process